# How can I set defaults for startup project and migration project in .NET Entity Framework Migrations?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli

I have my DbContext class living in a separate project from my entry point (startup) project. This means when I run `dotnet ef` CLI commands I need to specify the `--startup-project` and/or `--project` options every time. This works but is inconvenient.

I'm wondering if there is a way to save the values for these options somewhere so that I don't have to specify them every time I need to run a `dotnet ef` command. I'm thinking it would probably be somewhere in the startup project's `.csproj` file, or a separate `.json` defaults file that `dotnet` reads that points to the project where the migrations live.

I've searched around the CLI docs but don't see any capabilities like this mentioned. I'm hoping an option like this exists but is not documented (or that I missed it), or that somebody has a workaround to avoid having to specify these values every time.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Add-Migration" instead of "dotnet ef migrations add" (install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools first).

Then set the [Default Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNDYg.png) value to your EF Core project in the Package Manager Console.

Then you can just type "Add-Migration [migration name]" when adding a new migration.

Comment: This requires Visual Studio / Windows, right? I'm running on Mac and using the dotnet-cli.

Comment: Yea, this is with Visual Studio. I'm not sure how to do it with dotnet cli.